# Is it OK to have more than one handler for a command in CQRS?

Tags: cqrs

As title says, is it OK to have more than one handler for a command in CQRS? Looking at the simple CQRS example [here](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r) and [this line](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r/blob/af44b83bdc8021205a4360c5acd1c033d5b4a01b/SimpleCQRS/FakeBus.cs#L30) made me confused.

Here is the code:

```
public void Send<T>(T command) where T : Command
{
    List<Action<Message>> handlers;

    if (_routes.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out handlers))
    {
        if (handlers.Count != 1) throw new InvalidOperationException("cannot send to more than one handler");
        handlers[0](command);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("no handler registered");
    }
}
```

However, we have list of handlers per command type there which makes me more confused :) I am guessing that it's just an implementation detail and in ideal world, it should be OK but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: One command one handler. Event are pub/sub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have just one command handler for a command.  Commands are sent to request a change in the domain. Their implementation can be similar to DTOs, but they are not only transfer data. They provide communication in the abstract. So if there is one Command which has a general purpose and handled by lots of command handlers, this means that there is a separate logic on that command. And this can create inconsistency in domain. It will be difficult to find which handler is used for a specific command request.

And also when you change(add a property) the command for one specific command handler, that change is meaningless for other command handlers. And that is not desired.

If you need a concept like handling one command with more than one handlers, consider event sourcing which is also mentioned in CQRS.